# /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem heroku (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rvm

```
$ heroku 
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem heroku (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:18
```

Hello, I'm trying to get up and running with RVM and having problems. Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are just missing the gem. Are you using bundler?

Comment: Im having the same problem. Have you ever managed to solve it? It is a nasty stuff with RVM and I do not know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

that doesn't look like you've got RVM working - start with getting that working. Have you just installed it? Did you create a new bash session? Did you edit you bash_profile as per the instructions?

Does `rvm info` return anything for you?

Comment: ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p180"
    date:         "2011-02-18"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin10.8.0"
    patchlevel:   "2011-02-18 revision 30909"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]"